# CentOs 7 cant install mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, centos, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get a server up and running to run python scripts (Django framework) and such by using the mod_wsgi apache module to handle the scripts, however, it's not playing ball and I don't know enough to figure out what's happening or what I'm doing wrong.

I have been unable to come right using the `YUM` installer. So far, this is the output:

```
# sudo yum install mod_wsgi
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 169.255.59.74
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 169.255.59.74
 * base: mirror.wiru.co.za
 * epel: fedora.mirror.ac.za
 * extras: mirror.wiru.co.za
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * updates: mirror.wiru.co.za
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_wsgi.x86_64 0:3.4-12.el7_0 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: 
mod_wsgi-3.4-12.el7_0.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mod_wsgi-3.4-12.el7_0.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The first thing that jumped out is the dependency `httpd` which I tried (and failed) to install using yum. After this, I did some research and found out its an issue with cPanel and that apparently it prevents you from using `Yum` to install Apache modules and everywhere says I am supposed to use the interface but I have no idea how?

My goal is to figure out how I'm 'supposed' to be loading these modules to get around these obstacles and get my server going. Someone, please help!

I am running:

- CentOs 7.5
- Apache 2.4.34
- EasyApache 4
- cPanel 7.40
- PHP 5.6.38

Comment: With CentOS 7.5 the standard package for httpd is `httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.i686.rpm`. Not sure what yum is offering though.  How did you get httpd version 2.4.34? I would only use packages distributed with the .iso image or through yum.`mod_wsgi-3.4-12.el7_0.i686.rpm` looks goo too.

Comment: Wow thanks. You just made me realize that Apache and httpd is one and the same (Seems stupid but I didn't know that lol). So basically, the httpd 2.4.34 came pre-installed (I guess that would qualify as your .iso). Either way, problem remains. How do I actually install mod_wsgi? (Not showing up as an option in EasyApache 4, only some other thing called Mod_Proxy_uwsgi?

Comment: I will be setting up a CentOS 7.5 server in a few hours. I'll try installing `mod_wsgi` too and will get back to you.  The .iso image is downloadable from CentOS website and is used to create a CD/DVD of CentOS for installing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a CentOS 7.5 machine, I updated httpd (Apache) using yum to `2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1`.  Not exactly sure what your situation is with your pre-installed httpd version `2.4.34`.  Like I said in my comment above, I only trust versions of software available though yum.  Your version is above the standard version so you could experience unexpected results.

```
Updated:
  httpd.i686 0:2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1

Dependency Updated:
  httpd-devel.i686 0:2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1
  httpd-manual.noarch 0:2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1
  httpd-tools.i686 0:2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1
  mod_ldap.i686 0:2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1
  mod_ssl.i686 1:2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1
```

After upgrading `httpd`, I added mod_wsgi and it installed without any problems:

```
================================================================================
 Package            Arch           Version                 Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 mod_wsgi           i686           3.4-12.el7_0                base            75 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================

Install  1 Package

Total download size: 75 k
Installed size: 187 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
mod_wsgi-3.4-12.el7_0.i686.rpm                             |  75 kB   00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : mod_wsgi-3.4-12.el7_0.i686                                   1/1
  Verifying  : mod_wsgi-3.4-12.el7_0.i686                                   1/1

Installed:
  mod_wsgi.i686 0:3.4-12.el7_0

Complete!
```

I guess the point I'm trying to make is that if you use version of software no available through yum you can experience unexpected results.  I have been down this road before and I now use version of software only if they are available through yum.

The error you recieved: `Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664` is for a package not yet available through yum.  I performed a yum search on a CentOS 7.5 machine and it yields nothing available for httpd-mmn:

```
yum search httpd-mmn
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Warning: No matches found for: httpd-mmn
No matches found
```

So, you would have to compile it yourself possibly to get your setup to work.

Comment: Ok so I managed to figure it out. You are indeed correct. This is all to do with versions. Turns out EasyApache 4 no-longer supports the addition of custom optional mods which is why I couldn’t install mod_wsgi using that method. `yum` is also out of the question thanks to a sneaky system file in cPanel’s installation which prevents `yum install` commands from touching anything considered a system-related or cPanel handled modules or packages. Still managed to find a fix tho. Turns out mod_proxy_uwsgi is the latest supported wsgi alternative for running python in EasyApache 4.